# Spiral lichen forms

Tags: symmetry

I recently spotted many examples of a bilaterally symmetric lichen with a spiral form. This was on Navajo sandstone at the Utah-Arizona border. I found one paper that indicates this is likely Lecidea tessellata [https://www.colorado.edu/asmagazine-archive/node/933]. But I have found no indication of why a spiral pattern should form. It looks like the lichen first forms in an oval shape and then the center of the oval gets eaten away. Any ideas of why the spiral should form?

[image: spiral lichen]

[image: spiral lichen group]